# Conditional show/hide of autogenerated form elements in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have a ReactJS app where I am

A) reading a JSON input that describes a form's structure

B) *dynamically* generating a form from this JSON input (using document.createElement(..))

The JSON would look something like this:

```
{
   formElements: [
      {
          id: “dd1”, 
          type: “dropdown”,
          options: [ {value: “first”}, {value: “second”}]
      },
      {
          id: “tf1”, 
          type: “textfield”,
          showIf: “dd1 == ‘second’”
      }
   ]
}
```

Now the tricky thing is that the JSON input file not only describes which form elements (e.g. dropdown, radio button group, text field) etc should be present but it **ALSO describes show/hide logic for each element**. For example, if a particular dropdown selection is made, then a textfield should be shown (otherwise it should stay hidden).

This would normally be done in jQuery but I have heard jQuery is not a good idea with React.

If these were hardcoded form elements, I could easily code this show/hide logic. The problem is that the form elements are being *dynamically generated* (by reading that JSON file) and I need to apply this show/hide logic on the fly to these autogenerated form elements.

I'm not sure how to do this.

If any one has suggestions for approaches here, especially with examples, that would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to apply conditional rendering logic to the JSX code that is generating your form, but have you looked into using an existing form library like react-form or redux-forms? If you're relatively new to react, this would be a much easier route to get the results you want. I can't recommend a particular form library, but react-form notes that it handles dynamic data.

Here is my rough sketch of how you could manage this without using redux or a built-in form library.  This is a draft that was imagined but never executed, so treat it like psuedo-code and definitely not optimized:

```
    //import base form components up here (input, checkbox, etc)
    // Map the strings in your field object to the component imported or defined above

    const fieldSelector = {
      input : Input,
      textarea: TextArea,
      checkbox: CheckBox
    }

    Class CustomForm extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const fields = {}
        const byId = []

        // Note if there is any asynchronous data, you might want to put this logic
        // in componentDidMount
        // Create an array with each 'id'
        const byId = this.props.formData.map( item => item.id );
        // Create a map object listing each field by its id 
        this.props.formData.forEach( (field) => {
          fields[field.id] = field;
        }

        this.state = {
          fields, 
          byId,
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.checkVisibility = this.checkVisibility.bind(this);
      }

      // Need to add some additional logic if you're using checkboxes
      // Creates an event handler for each type of field
      handleChange(id) {
        return (event) => {
          const updatedFields = {...this.state.fields};
          updatedFields[id].value = event.target.value
          this.state.byId.forEach( fieldId => {
            updatedFields[fieldId].visible = checkVisibility(updatedFields, fieldId)};
          }  
          this.setState({fields: updatedFields})
        }
      }

      // You can either restructure your showIf or include a function above
      // to parse our the elements of the expression. 
      checkVisibility(updatedFields, fieldId) {
        const field = updatedFields[fieldId];
        const showIfId = field.showIf.triggerFieldId;
        const showIfValue = field.showIf.value;
        const operator = field.showIf.operator;
        switch(operator){
          case '===':
            return updatedFields[showIfId].value === ShowIfValue;
          case '<':
            return updatedFields[showIfId].value < ShowIfValue;
          //...fill in rest of operators here
          default: 
            return field.visible;
        }
      }

      render() {
        return this.state.byId.map( fieldId => {
          const field = this.state.fields[fieldId];
          const CustomField = FieldSelector[field.type]
          return (
            {field.visible && 
              <CustomField {insert whatever props from field} /> 
            }
          );
        });
      }
    }

    export default CustomForm
```